# Easiest way to check for a truthy value in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, and I want to check if any member is truthy.  I've tried looping over the array to check for falsy values:

`typeof val !== 'undefined' && val !== null && val != 0`

...but this seems needlessly verbose for something so simple, and error prone.

Comment: A "truthy" check of an array member is just `if (array[index]) {`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test for truthy members, just test them as booleans, and their truthiness will be determined.

```
const isAnyTruthy = array.some(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.some(Boolean)`.  Check out this [fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iqclccz0/).

Comment: I didn't vote on either answer, but Bergi's answer was posted slightly before yours and includes an (admittedly minor) explanation of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is use `!!` to check the truthy of the value.

```
const haveTruthyValue = arr.some(x => !!x)
```